# How do I listen to SMS Delivered broadcast inside of a Service?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, smsmanager

I'm trying to send an SMS from a background service and perform some action when it gets delivered.

Sending the SMS works. But the **OnReceive** method of my broadcast receiver is never called even when the SMS is delivered.

I have tested the broadcast receiver with other actions and it works.

For example adding the action "**android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF**" works just fine.

It only fails to work with the custom action "**SMS_DELIVERED**" which I send in the **PendingIntent**.

Below is my code:

```
public class SendMessageService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "SendMessageService";
public static final String SMS_DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
private BroadcastReceiver deliveryBroadcastReceiver = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    intentFilter.addAction(SMS_DELIVERED);

    intentFilter.setPriority(100);

    deliveryBroadcastReceiver = new DeliverReceiver();

    registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

    Log.d(TAG, "Service onCreate: deliveryBroadcastReceiver is registered.");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String phoneNumber = extras.getString("PHONE_NUMBER");
    String msg = extras.getString("msg");

    sendSMS(phoneNumber, msg);

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: Sent SMS");

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void sendSMS (String phoneNumber, String msg){

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, msg, null, deliveredPI);
}

public class DeliverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Delivered onReceive called");

        // Do something here
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Not all carriers offer delivery reports, though, and if yours doesn't, then the delivery `PendingIntent` will just never fire. Are you sure your carrier provides delivery reports? What happens if, just to test, you temporarily pass `deliveredPI` for the sent `PendingIntent` instead? That is, `smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, msg, deliveredPI, null)`. Does that fire?

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried what you said and the receiver fires. So I guess the problem is with our carrier then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is actually fine. Seems like the problem was that my Telecom Carrier (EthioTel) did not provide reliable sms delivered reports.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes looking: I have a `PendingIntent` for SMS Delivery that was working perfectly until I updated to Android 11.  I have not been able to find any information with regards to this issue, but a Pixel 4a with Android 10 works fine, but my Pixel 4 with Android 11 does not.  SMS Sent `PendingIntents` are still working as expected on both devices.